# Tailwind ignore content config

Tags: tailwind-css

I have created my own component lib using Tailwind.
When I use this inside my application I dont want to include some css file etc.
I just want tailwind to scan my components in the node_modules, like NextUI does it and add used classes.

```
content: [
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './node_modules/@my/components/dist/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
],
```

But for some reason the styles I used in this component don't get picket up by Tailwind.
[image]

Generated file:

```
import { jsxs as i } from "react/jsx-runtime";
import { tv as m } from "tailwind-variants";
const n = m({
  base: "font-medium bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-full active:opacity-80",
  variants: {
    color: {
      primary: "bg-blue-500 text-white",
      secondary: "bg-purple-500 text-white",
      secondaryTwo: "bg-red-500 text-black"
    },
    size: {
      sm: "text-sm",
      md: "text-base",
      lg: "px-4 py-3 text-lg"
    }
  },
  compoundVariants: [
    {
      size: ["sm", "md"],
      class: "px-3 py-1"
    }
  ],
  defaultVariants: {
    size: "md",
    color: "primary"
  }
}), l = ({ size: e, className: o, color: r, label: t, children: s, ref: a }) => /* @__PURE__ */ i(
  "button",
  {
    ref: a,
    type: "button",
    title: t,
    className: n({ className: o, color: r, size: e }),
    children: [
      s,
      t
    ]
  }
);
export {
  l as Button
};
```

What am I doing wrong?